# Assignment to expression with array type AND request for member in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, dev-c++

Im trying to declarate this variables of the type of my struct and having this errors, code is about a elections. CANDIDATO is a portuguese word and means candidates, i think i dont need do translate so much of this

```
struct candidatos{
    int  numCandidato;
    char nomeCandidado[10];
    char partidoCandidato[3];
    char cargoCandidato[1];
     int votos;
    float porcentagem;
};
struct candidatos listar[11];

int main(){
    //CANDIDATO 01
    listar[0].numCandidato = 111;
    strcpy(listar[0].nomeCandidado, "ABC");
    strcpy(listar[0].partidoCandidato, "ABC");
    strcpy(listar[0].cargoCandidato, "ABC");
    listar[0].votos = 0;
}

////ERROR START'S HERE


int iniciarVotacao(){

    struct candidatos presidente; 
    struct candidatos deputado;
    int votoPresidente = 0;
    int votoDeputado = 0;
    int i = 0;

    presidente.nomeCandidado = 0; //°1 erro
    deputado.numCandidato = 0; // erro

    printf("Número do candidato para a Presidência => ");
    scanf("%d", &votoPresidente);
    printf("\nNúmero do candidato para Deputado => ");
    scanf("%d", &votoDeputado);

    for(i = 0 ; i < 11 ; i++){
            if(listar[i].numCandidato == votoPresidente && listar.numCandidato < 50){
                presidente = listar[i];
            }// 2° erro acontece
            if(listar[i].numCandidato == votoPresidente && listar.numCandidato > 1000){
                deputado = listar[i];
            }
    }
```

Comment: Also `listar.numCandidato` should be `listar[i].numCandidato`

Comment: Some of those `strcpy()` calls in `main()` suffer from buffer overflow. `strcpy(listar[0].partidoCandidato, "ABC");` and `strcpy(listar[0].cargoCandidato, "ABC");` will overwrite 4 elements (including the string's null terminator) of the `partidoCandidato` and `cargoCandidato` array members, but the array members are only 3 and 1 elements long, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rectified the errors that concerned you. Below is the corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct candidatos{
  int  numCandidato;
  char nomeCandidado[10];
  char partidoCandidato[4];
  char cargoCandidato[4];
  int votos;
  float porcentagem;
} listar[11];

int main(){
  //CANDIDATO 01
  listar[0].numCandidato = 111;
  strcpy(listar[0].nomeCandidado, "ABC");
  strcpy(listar[0].partidoCandidato, "ABC");
  strcpy(listar[0].cargoCandidato, "ABC");
  listar[0].votos = 0;
}

int iniciarVotacao(){
  struct candidatos presidente;
  struct candidatos deputado;

  int votoPresidente = 0;
  int votoDeputado = 0;
  int i = 0;

  presidente.nomeCandidado[0] = '0';
  deputado.numCandidato = 0;

  printf("Número do candidato para a Presidência => ");
  scanf("%d", &votoPresidente);
  printf("\nNúmero do candidato para Deputado => ");
  scanf("%d", &votoDeputado);

  for(i = 0 ; i < 11 ; i++){
    if(listar[i].numCandidato == votoPresidente && listar[i].numCandidato < 50){
      presidente = listar[i];
    }// 2° erro acontece
    if(listar[i].numCandidato == votoPresidente && listar[i].numCandidato > 1000){
      deputado = listar[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Your first error with `presidente.nomeCandidado = 0;` was because you were trying to assign an integer value to an array pointer. You must index your array beforehand.

`listar` is an array of structures, as per your code `listar[i].numCandidato`. You cannot at a later stage treat it just as a structure, and not an array of structures. As you did inside your for loop, `listar.numCandidato`. That had to be altered too.

You also made a mistake in declaring only 3 and 1 indices for `partidoCandidato` and `cargoCandidato`, respectively, inside your `candidatos` struct definition. They must be 4 at a minimum because you are assigning them `ABC`. Which consists of 3 characters and an extra character reserved for the null terminator `\0` that indicates an end of an array.

As a side note. Since you declared `listar[11]` globally, right after defining the structure that it utilizes. Why not simply declare it right after the closing square bracket of the `candidatos` structure, instead of writing a whole new line? As I did above.